# PHP to generate HTML radio buttons

Tags: php, html, forms, function, loops

Ok, im unsure on how to explain what i want (probably why i cant figure out how to do it) but basically, I have the following html form:

```
                <p class="ratingButtons">
                    <input type="radio" class="spacing" name="moRating1" value="1">1
                    <input type="radio" class="spacing" name="moRating1" value="2">2
                    <input type="radio" class="spacing" name="moRating1" value="3">3
                    <input type="radio" class="spacing" name="moRating1" value="4">4
                    <input type="radio" class="spacing" name="moRating1" value="5">5
                    <input type="radio" class="spacing" name="moRating1" value="6">6
                </p>
```

What i'm wanting to do is some sort of PHP loop to print whichever one is selected, then turn it into a function so i could reuse it for different questions (like the one below)
therefore cutting down on the amount of HTML is used..

```
                    <p class="ratingButtons">
                    <input type="radio" class="spacing" name="moRating2" value="1">1
                    <input type="radio" class="spacing" name="moRating2" value="2">2
                    <input type="radio" class="spacing" name="moRating2" value="3">3
                    <input type="radio" class="spacing" name="moRating2" value="4">4
                    <input type="radio" class="spacing" name="moRating2" value="5">5
                    <input type="radio" class="spacing" name="moRating2" value="6">6
                </p>
```

Any ideas? or tips, im pretty new to php so as newbie friendly as possible please!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function could look something like this:

```
function generateRadioButtons($name, $values = 6) {
    $o = '<p class="ratingButtons">' . "\n";
    for ($v = 1; $v <= $values; $v++) {
        $selected = !empty($_POST[$name]) && $_POST[$name] == $v ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
        $o.= '<input type="radio" class="spacing" name="' . $name . '" value="' . $v . '"' . $selected . '>' . $v . "\n";
    }
    $o.= '</p>' . "\n";
    return $o;
}
```

And with this function, you can easily output your options:

```
echo generateRadioButtons('moRating1');
echo generateRadioButtons('moRating2');
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/67893)**.

Comment: This is exactly what i need, could you run me through where your getting the $v and $o from? just so i understand the code a bit better

Comment: `$v` is a counter variable used for looping. `$o` is the variable in which the HTML is stored.

Answer (score 1):

It's so easy:

```
<?php
function radio_selected($selected,$array){
$len=count($array);
for($i=0;$i < $len;++$i){
$num=$i+1;
$class=($selected==$array[$i])?'checked="checked"':'';
$a.='<input type="radio" class="spacing" name="moRating'.$num.'" value="'.$num.'"'.$class.'> '.$num;
}
return $a;
}
// --- And you can use it now
$array=Array('a','b','c');
$selected=$_POST['b']; // For example b
echo radio_selected($selected,$array);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

$options- No of options you want

$sel_val- Selected value of the vote to show it selected

$name - Name From which you want the values in the post

```
function rating_buttons($options,$sel_value,$name)
    {
        $output ='<p class="ratingButtons">';
        for($i=0;$i<$options;$i++)
        {
         $value=$i+1;   
         $output .= '<input type="radio" class="spacing" ';
            if($sel_value==$value)
                $output .='checked="Checked"';
            else
                $output .=''; 

                $output .='name="'.$name.'" value="'.$value.'">'.$value;
        }
        $output .='</p>';
        echo $output;
    }


    rating_buttons(5,3,'abc');
```